# EF - Can not delete an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why does this code not work? It inserts an object but does not delete it

```
public int Toggle(RequestArchive RequestArchiveObj)
{
   var ra = DataContext.RequestArchives.Where(rec => rec.UserId == RequestArchiveObj.UserId && rec.RequestId == RequestArchiveObj.RequestId);

   if(ra.Count() > 0)
   {
        foreach (var item in ra)
        {                    
            DataContext.DeleteObject(item);
        }
   }
   else
   {
        DataContext.AddToRequestArchives(RequestArchiveObj);
   }

   DataContext.SaveChanges();
   return RequestArchiveObj.Id;
}
```

Comment: @f_puras , it is a C# method

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you set a breakpoint in the `foreach` to see that you get in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a potentially dangerous issue with your code and your problem might relate to that:

If you loop through your query object (the object returned by `DataContext.RequestArchives.Where()`) without executing it, you're going to have a roundtrip to the database for every single item in the loop. This is called the [**N+1 selects problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem).

You can mitigate this using the `ToList()` method:

```
var ra = DataContext.RequestArchives
                    .Where(rec => 
                           rec.UserId == RequestArchiveObj.UserId && 
                           rec.RequestId == RequestArchiveObj.RequestId)
                    .ToList(); // this executes the query
// ...
foreach (var item in ra) // without ToList() this will query every item by itself
{                    
    DataContext.DeleteObject(item); // and this might collide with the query
}
```

I'm not sure about this, but maybe the deletion problem occurs because you try to delete objects while still querying them through the `foreach` loop. If that is the case, it should work once you're using `ToList()` as recommended above.

Comment: WOOOW :O , That is very clever , Thanks Dennis , your answer is amazing me !!!!! Thanks for awe some answer